# How do I find out appropriate DOM method to get position in 'px' of selection in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my content editable div I have been managed to get the selection using

```
document.getSelection()
```

and able to get the relevant data using:

```
getRangeAt(0)
```

Now I want to get the position of selection in 'px' not the caret in regard to div. Also how can I able to figure out relevant methods using JS documentation or on my own.

Here is my JSX code:

```
showPos() {
if (document.getSelection().toString()) {
        console.log(document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects()[0]);
      }
}
<div className={s.editorDesc} tabIndex="1" contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning="true" ref={(input) => {
                    this.editorDesc = input;
                  }} onMouseUp={(e) => {
                    this.showPos(e);
                  }}>
                  <p>Description of Article</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: Try using [`getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getClientRects) on one of the selection's [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt) objects

Comment: It returns coordinate with respect to window.

Comment: Does subtracting the enclosing div's client position suffice? That would result in div-relative pixels

Comment: Currently using this approach but isn't there any available method which returns value like caret position?

Comment: Caret position is a range object too, just get the range object and check for `range.collapsed` to make sure it's a caret, then if it is do `getCLientRects()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working Fiddle

```js
$("#div").on('mousedown mouseup keydown keyup',function(){
 //First get position of caret
  var caretPos=getCaretPosition($(this)[0]);
 //Selection text
  var selectionText=window.getSelection().toString();
  //inner html of editable div
  var divString=$(this).html();
  //Divide inner html in two parts as divided by caret
  var leftString=divString.substring(0,caretPos);
  var rightString=divString.substring(caretPos,divString.lenght);
  
  /*
   Now check if selection text is present at right of caret or left of caret
  */
  var startPointer=caretPos;
  var endPointer=caretPos;
  var selectionLength=selectionText.length;
  if(rightString.indexOf(selectionText)==0){
   endPointer=caretPos+selectionLength;
  }else{
   startPointer=caretPos-selectionLength;
  }
  /*
  Now divide string in three parts
  */
  var str1=divString.substring(0,startPointer);
  var str2=divString.substring(startPointer,endPointer);
  var str3=divString.substring(endPointer,divString.length);
  
  
  $("#div2").html(str1+'<span class="caret" id="posTracker1"></span>'+str2+'<span class="caret" id="posTracker2"></span>'+str3);
  var startPos=$("#posTracker1").offset();
  $("#pointerStart").html("Start: "+JSON.stringify(startPos));
  $("#pointerStart").css({
   top:startPos.top-40,
    left:startPos.left-30
  });
  var endPos=$("#posTracker2").offset();
  $("#pointerEnd").html("End: "+JSON.stringify(endPos));
  $("#pointerEnd").css({
   top:endPos.top+10,
    left:endPos.left-30
  });
 
});

function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
  var caretPos = 0,
    sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
        caretPos = range.endOffset;
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
      var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
      editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
      var tempRange = range.duplicate();
      tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
      tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
      caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
    }
  }
  return caretPos;
}
```

```css
#div{
  background:#ddd;
  padding:10px;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}
#div2{
  background:#ddd;
  padding:10px;
  position:absolute;
}
.caret{
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:green;
}
.pointer{
  width:auto;
  padding:3px;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-Index:999999;
}
#pointerStart{
  background:#2980b9;
}

#pointerEnd{
  background:#16a085;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
<div id="div" contenteditable="true">
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
<div id="pointerStart" class="pointer">
</div>
<div id="pointerEnd" class="pointer">
</div>
```

To get coordinates of selection I did following steps.
 1. first find the position of the caret.
 2. get selection text
 3. now check if the selection is on the right side of caret or on the left side.
 4. now divide full string into three parts "preselection","selection","postselection"
 5. Create exact replica of div and put same content with span separating three strings
 6. get coordinates of these spans

I have shown an example of simple text with extra efforts same can be implemented on HTML too.